# Using javascript to get the value of a textbox in Master Page ContentPlaceHolders

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, master-pages

I have an asp.net 4.0 framework application that consists of a Masterpage and contentplaceholders. I have a .js file that does validations on the data entered by the user. How can I call a textbox "txtFirstName" (from the .js file) that is in a ContentPlaceHodler "cphBody" ?

**Update (code):**
**.aspx**

```
<asp:TextBox id="txtFirstName" runat="server" CssClass="webForm" Width="250px" MaxLength="100"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:Button id="btnContinue" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" onclientclick="document.getElementById('cphHeaderContent_AlertTimeMsgBox').value = GetSeconds(); return ValidateUser(1);" CssClass="webButton" Text="Continue" OnClick="btnContinue_Click" />
```

**.js**

```
function ValidateUser(valFormCount)
{
    var objTextBox;

    objTextBox = document.getElementById("txtFirstName");
```

I have tried `document.getElementById("<%= txtFirstName.ClientID %>")` but that did not work(a null value is passed).  How can I accomplish this?

Comment: @ClaudioRedi Not everything has to be jQuery...

Comment: @ClaudioRedi..... Nope... that would be too easy

Comment: @TheZ: I didn't say he has to use it, just asked if he's using it now although I wasn't almost sure that not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This asp.net notation

```
document.getElementById("<%= txtFirstName.ClientID %>")
```

is not valid inside a js file

You could set [`ClientIDMode="Static"`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx) for the `TextBox`. If you do this, you'll be able to get the element by id with this

**ASPX**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

**JS**

```
var textbox = document.getElementById("txtFirstName");
```

**About `ClientIDMode="Static"`**

> This mode does exactly what you think it would, it makes the client side ID static. Meaning that what you put for the ID is what will be used for the client side ID.  Warning, this means that if a static ClientIDMode is used in a repeating control the developer is responsible for ensuring client side ID uniqueness.

Comment: Still getting null after trying your suggestion

Comment: @DotNetRookie: be sure that you call getElementById when the element is already added to the DOM.

Comment: ahh... there is no <form> in the html. It's using ContentPlaceHolders (and then tables inside the contentplaceholders)

Comment: @DotNetRookie: ClientIDMode="Static" is for the TextBox

Comment: wow... that was crazy. I think it works (for now). Gracias Senor